# BCDEdit - How to set device partition to a number (not c:)

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, bootmgr, dualboot

I would like to add a new entry to my Windows bootmgr, which on another partition (5th one). What should I write after device partition=... to load the 5th partition?

Answer (score 2):

Just use whatever letter is assigned to that partition *at this moment*, and it will be stored as the correct partition reference.

The BCD doesn't really store drive letters (nor numeric 'HarddiskVolume#' paths) in the first place – bcdedit simply shows them for convenience, but what's actually stored is only the partition's UUID.

(You might notice that the {bootmgr} entry is shown as having "partition=S:" when the EFI System Partition is mounted at S:, but the same entry is shown with "partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1" when the partition is not mounted. That indicates the displayed value is dynamically translated by bcdedit.)

Comment: The problem is that the OS I want to add (ubuntu) is on 3 partitions and not on a volume, and I can't assign a letter to a partition

Answer (score 0):

Adding a boot manager on the volume in question would solve the problem: the boot manager would show all available OSes on the volume, and let you choose one of them to boot from.

Comment: As I said on the upper answer, I have 3 partition, on my Windows volume, then, how could I put them on a new volume?